# How to stop propagation in Vuetify v-switch?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

I'm using Vuetify and I have `v-data-table`. When I click on row `v-dialog` must open. Also I have `v-switch` inside rows in my `v-data-table`. **My problem comes** when I click on the `v-switch` it switches, but also propagates and opens my `v-dialog`. 
In my [codepen](https://codepen.io/stanimirsp5/pen/zYvGbBe?editors=1010) I have three examples of v-switch click events.

- First is with `@click.native.stop`. Here I deal with propagation successfully, but click event is not only in the v-switch, but it covers the whole container *(colored in red in example)*
- My second try is with `@change`. Here switch event is activated only on v-switch toggle, but when I click on the v-switch the v-dialog opens too. So with `@change` it doesn't work properly too.
- The third try is with `@change.stop`, but without desired result, its same as my second try.

My question is - Is there a way to stop the propagation *(with no side effects as in my first example)* and when I click on v-switch to toggle only the switch , but not and the v-dialog behind?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just add `@click.native.stop` to your `<v-switch>`.

See it working: https://codepen.io/andrei-gheorghiu/pen/RwWPONL

**Note**: To limit the area in which the click is captured, you have to change `.v-input--switch`s `display` value to `inline-block`:

```
.v-input--switch {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

And you don't actually need to stop more than `click`, as the dialog only opens on click. As you can see, you can use <kbd>Tab</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd> to toggle the switch and the modal is not opening.

Answer (score 4):

My workaround is to use `@click.native.stop` to stop propagation and `@change` for event

```
<v-switch
    v-model="item.isActive"
    @click.native.stop
    @change="toggleActive(item)">
</v-switch>
```

Comment: need to read carefully next time, I thought that you're telling me to replace `@change` with `@click`